# SQL and MYSQL difference

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to understand the difference b/n SQL and MYSQL. does it is like Java and Eclipse?

Comment: SQL is a general name for a language that talks to databases.  MySQL is a specific database product.  When referring to a language, it is a dialect of SQL.

Comment: When you say "SQL", are you referring to general SQL language or Microsoft SQL Server (common but inaccurate terminology) or ??

Answer (score 2):

Structured Query Language or SQL is a language for querying relational databases, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

MySQL is a relational database, not a language.

You use SQL code to query the data in MySQL so they are used together.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a standard language specification, originally published by ANSI and now published by ISO. It is not a specific software implementation, it's just a technical document describing the language.

MySQL is one product that supports the SQL language. There are other software products made by other companies that also support the SQL language. For example: SQLite, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, and others. These are all independent implementations, based on each company's original code.

None of the implementations available match the SQL specification perfectly. There are numerous features in the spec that are specifically marked as "optional" and left for the vendor to implement if they wish.

In other cases, the vendor has supplemented SQL with some features that are useful and demanded by customers, even though they aren't in the SQL specification.

Trivia: indexes are such a common feature of RDBMS implementation that we assume it's part of the standard language, but SQL does not mention indexes. In every SQL product, indexes are a vendor addition.

Also, there's a lot more work needed to implementing complete RDBMS software besides just the SQL language. Storage, query optimization, compression, security, administration tools, user interfaces, APIs, networking, logging, monitoring, and other features. So the SQL language is just a small part of the work it takes.

You could compare this to C++. The C++ programming language is defined by its own ANSI specification document. Many companies have created C++ compiler products for one platform or another. They must comply with the language specification, even though their respective product implementing that language is based on their own independent and original code.

You asked:

> [is] it is like Java and Eclipse?

A closer analogy would be the [Java language and virtual machine specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) versus the popular [Java Platform Standard Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), which is an implementation of the language specification.

There are other companies that have implemented their own Java VM products (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines), although they are not as widely used as the Oracle implementation.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is a standard that the implementors of MySQL did a quick skim of, then sort of went their own way on a lot of things. Very loosely:

> SQL is a language and MySQL is a *dialect* of that language.

MySQL is also an implementation related to that dialect: The `mysqld` executable is what performs actual database operations. SQL being a standard is little more than a document, it doesn't run, it has no reference implementation.